# Wordpress Permalink Doesn't Work Ubuntu Server AWS

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-ec2

I try this tutorial but nothing happen

http://guiem.info/permalinks-on-wordpress-amazon-ec2/

apache2.conf directory codes

```
    <Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    #None
        AllowOverride All 
    Require all granted
</Directory>


<Directory "/var/www/html">

    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks


    AllowOverride All


    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory "/var/www/html/wordpress">

    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks

    AllowOverride All

    Require all granted
</Directory>


#<Directory /srv/>
#   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
#   AllowOverride None
#   Require all granted
#</Directory>
```

Of course, I always restart apache every time I make a change

If I do not use permalinks wordpress works perfect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this](http://www.howtosolutions.net/2017/07/wordpress-fixing-not-found-error-when-using-pretty-permalinks/) article, this can happen when **mod_rewrite** module is not enabled in Apache configuration file.

Comment: Thank you very much sir.